# How to rename is_active in user table in django?

Tags: python, django

This is my user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(
        verbose_name="ID", serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True
    )
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), max_length=255, unique=True)
    avatar = models.CharField(_("avatar"), max_length=128, default="")
    username = None

    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Now, I need to rename `is_active` to `active`.
I originally wanted to cancel is_active like username, and then create a new active field

```
is_active = None
active = models.BooleanField(_("active"), default=False)
```

This does not seem to work, and I received an error message

```
 (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to 'is_active', which does not refer to a Field.
```

Comment: As the error message suggests, can you also include the `admin.py` details for your `User` model? It's likely that you are still using the old renamed field in there, just replace it with your new field name. And while we are at it, do you have a concrete reason for changing the default field? It may mess with default authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend removing or renaming a built-in field because you'll undoubtedly get more error messages similar to the ones you're already seeing. If you don't plan to use it, you can default it to something (for instance, `username` field can be defaulted to the email address).

You can also create a [property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods) field if you want to reference an already existing field. This may work for your `active` field. The only issue with this approach is that you will still need to update `is_active` if you want to change the value of `active`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def active(self):
        return self.is_active
```